# Show Dialler : Problems

Tags: android

I have an edit text.. I need to restrict the edit text with numbers. So i gave

```
     EditText phoneNumber
     phoneNumber.setKeyListener(DialerKeyListener.getInstance());
```

But in some phones..when i click the edit text 2 characters are shown in the dialler 'p' and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
phoneNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, if you are using xml to generate the layout, you can add:

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

in your EditText.